# How do you remove a custom event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

Here is my code to create a custom event that is working:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("Event"); //creat custom event
evt.initEvent("fac_sel", true, true); //initialize the event
evt.objIndex = "some test data"; //add custom data
document.dispatchEvent(evt); //fire event!
```

For some reason the following code results in "undefined"

```
document.removeEventListener("Event","fac_sel", true);
```

Answer (score 5):

The addEventListener and removeEventListener methods do not return anything. Hence the call `document.removeEventListener("Event", "fac_sel", true)` will display as undefined in a debugger or assign `undefined` to a variable.

Check out the [removeEventListener method on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener) for more information.